# change index of same objects (Unity)

Tags: string, for-loop, if-statement, unity-game-engine, contains

When the same text objects, collider of that objects enabling. I taking the objects with sort I mean I can only take zero element, not others. But sometimes text of zero element and text of any element being same e.g. zero element and 4th element. then I can take each other. But I have a problem about this. When i take non-zero same text element, then I have to set index of zero element to index of non-zero text element.

For example. "E","U","L","E". now zero element and third element is same. When i take the third element I want to set index of zero element to index of destroyed (so third) element. How can i do this?

This code part in Update Method

```cs
if (letterPanel.childCount > 0)
    {
        string letter = letterPanel.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text;
        letterPanel.GetChild(0).GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < letterPanel.childCount; i++)
        {
            if (letter.Contains(letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text))
            {
                letterPanel.GetChild(0).transform.SetSiblingIndex(i);
                letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, but if all elements hold in list? Then you can just work with list elements, dont need all time get child elements.

Comment: Actullay I put the setsiblinIndex code to onTriggerEnter2D and it works but if text of first element or second element has same text of any object, then indexes are intermingling. e.g. "M","O","A","M","O","A". in this text zero, first and second element has same object. zero element is same with third element, first element is same with fourth element, second element is same with fifth element. As such, the indexes are intermingling

Comment: if (letter.Contains(letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text && letterPanel.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>() != letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>())

i mean, what about add validation for check that object not same.

Comment: giving this error:  Operator `&&' cannot be applied to operands of type `string' and `bool'. I wrote text at last but giving error again

Comment: I fixed the code but does not work. same problem again

Comment: Try this one.  (letter.Contains(letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text && letterPanel.GetChild(0) != letterPanel.GetChild(i))

Comment: your code giving same error again. Operator &&' cannot be applied to operands of type string' and `bool'. when i write contains all of it, then giving cannot convert Transform to string error

Comment: if (letter.Contains(letterPanel.GetChild(i).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text) && letterPanel.GetChild(0) != letterPanel.GetChild(i)) because forgot ) after contains logic.

Comment: same again. the indexes are intermingling. never changed